# "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" tried all

Tags: java, android, dalvik

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 - After updating Android SDK & ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125039/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-after-updating-android-sdk-a)

I've readed a lot of posts about this error, and tried most of the solutions but i can't find a solution for my project.

Eclipse only show me the error when I add into my AndroidManifest this line of code:

```
 <!-- this is the problem line -->
 <permission android:name="com.myproject.myproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />    
 <!-- end of problem line -->

 <uses-permission android:name="com.myproject.myproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

any solution please?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your permissions names may be wrong. Check your permissions names:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: can you tell me exactly what is wrong? I've followed the tutorial and build the test project and it works. They have the same manifest format like me

Comment: Actually I'm not sure about the error. Why are you using the same permission name two times? What if you remove the problem line?

Comment: it builds ok, but the library doesn't seem to work.

Comment: UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/fastdove/notifications/library/Manifest$permission;

Comment: Have a look at those two threads:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645247/problem-registering-for-c2dm-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121061/c2dm-how-to-use-c2d-message-permission

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue earlier, In my case this was beacause I have included jar files, and they both have same package name. I removed one of them, thn everything worked like charm. Makesure you also don't have same package problem. If you include any jars or Library Project.